# Getting local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge''

Tags: php, laravel, env

I'm ocassionally getting this error on my local environment (XAMPP):

```
local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge''
```

.Env file is written as follows:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=Dg4KFyDhAePtob94RUZ4frMCak4nHSF2

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=items
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

config/database.php:

```
<?php

return [


    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path().'/database.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

It's Laravel 5.1. It happens very rarely, but it still happens.

What might cause the problem?

Comment: Please show contents of '/config/database.php' file.

Comment: please confirm your .env file is that .env or .env.example.

Comment: As @ImtiazPabel said, probably the problem is that no `.env` file exists and OP just editing `.env.example`

Comment: You said, "I'm ocassionally getting this error on my local environment" what do you mean by occasionally?

Comment: Something is wrong with your .env file. Look, exception says 'Access denied to database forge'. 'Forge' is default value in your config, it will be applied if environment variable was not found.

Comment: try to add DB_CONNECTION=mysql (or whatever u are using

Comment: .env file exists for sure,  along with .env.example .  By ocassionally I mean once in every few days.  It shouldn't happen at all.  It doesn’t happen on server,  just on my local machine,  XAMPP on Windows 7